# how to close an external iframe src

Tags: java, php, html, iframe

How do i close am iframe src with a click event witing the iframe ?
Lets say i have this parent html

```
<body>
<script>
document.write("<iframe src='default.html' id="myFrame" width='100%'></iframe>");


function closeIframe(){
   $('#myFrame').remove();
}
</script>
</body>
```

and i have an iframe default.html with codes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="iframe" value="" onchange="parent.closeIframe()">
```

I want to be able to close the iframe on clicking the checkbox. The above codes does not work for me. I need assistance.

Comment: If the iFrame content is from another origin than the parent, forget it. If from same, then no need for an iFrame. Pop a div and ajax the content if needed

Answer (score 0):

This requires cooperation between the outer and the inner sites + a piece of Javascript on both sites.

On the outer side, a listener is required to react on a posted message:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {

  if (event.origin !== 'https://inner.example.com') return;
  if (typeof event.data != 'string') return;
  
  // do your stuff...
  if (message == 'hello_world') {
    // react on the message
  }
});
```

The URL "https://inner.example.com" refers to the site inside the iframe.
From there, a command is posted to the outer site like this. The check for the origin of the message is to reject messages from other (unknown) sites.

```
parent.postMessage('hello_world', 'https://outer.example.com');
```

The URL "https://outer.example.com" refers to the site which contains the iframe.

The message could be arbitrary, however in this example only a string is accepted. The content of the string can be anything...

You should note that browsers may prevent this message sending, if outer and inner are from different domains (security policy).

Comment: tnx for your contribution Lars. Your answer is too complex for a beginner like me to understand. I would appreciate a simple code on how to close an iframe with the checkbox or any click event within the iframe(bearing in mind tht the iframe is not within the parent script, but an external script within the same domain)

Comment: Your approach doesn't work anymore, because fraudulent sites exploited the "easy" things it in the past...